# Div Sidebar height and zooming

Tags: css

For a live demo, visit my website @ http://hello-world.cu.cc . 
Make sure to check out the homepage, the projects page and the comments page. Each of these pages has the same sidebar with different styles applied to it. This is to show you what I have tried and the problems it causes.

I am making a website which has a sidebar to the left and the main content to the right. The problem i'm having is to do with the sidebar. I have it floating to the left and this is fine untill i zoom in on the webpage and all of a sudden the sidebar moves position which wrecks up the whole layout. I've tried to fix this by setting the position of the sidebar to absolute and the position of the container to relative. Now this solves the zooming problem because when I zoom in now it stays in the same position. However, since the position is now absolute, the page doesn't automatically get longer to accomodate the sidebar. The temporary solution I am using at the moment is to position the sidebar absolutely to fix the zooming problem and then adding a max height as well as `overflow:auto` to provide scroll bars that can be used to scroll the sidebar.

Comment: if you find a clean, cross browser safe and efficient way to handle users "zooming" then let us know. As it stands this is a common headache. However as a end user, when I attempt to zoom on a website I do expect shit to stop looking good. I am augmenting the original display.

Comment: To further outline what I am saying above: Browsers/OS handle and implement zooming in a non-standard way. Just like scroll bars. It will be almost impossible for you to handle this in all scenarios, So why even bother trying. The website looks good at 100%. If the user augments the display then they are at fault and can always just turn it back. It would be like trying to circumvent your site looking like crap if I disable CSS.

Comment: @areke I have created my website using includes and therefore it will be difficult for me to show you all the code. Also I am using If Statements in PHP to output different codes and styles depending on the condition. You can view the source code from the link I have given to my website. Other than that, I don't know how to show you it all. Sorry

Comment: I agree with rlemon on this one. If the user zooms into a page, they know they are going to screw it up. The website is fine as it is.

Comment: It doesn't like some of the widths, somewhere (haven't found it yet).  It goes screwy when I zoom, but if I make the page wider it eventually pops back into place.  That suggests to me that there are conflicts with a percentage-based width, or maybe you need a wrapper for the whole thing with an appropriate `min-width` value declared... not sure

Comment: @rlemon Thanks for the information. I wasn't aware that zooming was a common problem. I thought it was happening to me because I am relatively new to coding and therefore do not know enough to fix it. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I had hoped to get this fixed but I will take your advice and leave it as it is. Instead I will add a note to my website informing users of the problem. Thanks again mate :)

Comment: @Mike Well, I have used percentages to set the width for 3 things: the header, footer and content div. The header and footer are at 100% whilst the content div is at 73%. Il change it to pixels and will let you know if that solves it. Thanks for the reply

Comment: For instance: Chrome adjusts the elements `zoom` css properties. IE does something different, and IIRC safari does something else (not sure what, you can google this). This means even if you think you've fixed it on one browser, the next can screw with you, or if Chrome ever decides to change how it handles this (again it's non-standard, no spec, nothing to go off), you're site will be broken again. Zooming is a browser *feature*, not a CSS or JS or any other language function (css has a zoom property, but that is not the same). You cannot know how browser features will or will not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things that seem to be causing problems.

- #header has `min-width:100%`
- #main has `width:1100px`

Fix those and you'll be on your way.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail please? Like how should I fix them? By making them both into pixels or percentages? Or by changing the sizes of the widths? Or removing the min-width? Since I'm new to coding I do not know what differences these changes will make so I'm having a little trouble "fixing" them. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't correctly understand the question.... but from what I see, your layout changes when you reach down to a certain screen size and you want it to flow correctly.  If that's the case, you just need to drop those sizes and then the page will flow into the viewport of your browser.

Comment: You were right. It was the height and min-height that was causing me problems. Thank you so much mate :)

Comment: Oh and I set the width:100%; min-width:1100px; for both my header and footer to fix it, just in case you were wondering. It was suggested by Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Like Randy Hunt pointed out above, the biggest issue is being caused by your `#header`.  I would apply these to your header: `position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;`, then you'll need to adjust all the elements where you're currently using a negative margin by applying a positive margin as well.  Take the 150px height of your header and add the negative margins to find the new positive margin value (so a -138px top margin would become 12px).

Also, instead of `min-width: 100%;` I would do something like `width: 100%; min-width: 1100px;` or whatever the width is.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on what Randy Hunt said because I didn't understand what changes to make exactly. For both the header and footer I set the width:100%; and width:1100px; just like you told me to and it seems to have fixed the problem. So once again thank you so much!